# How to retrieve difference in value between a value of the current and previous rows without using temp table?

Tags: sql, select, google-bigquery

I want to retrieve difference in Counter column(below is a sample data) between a value of the current and previous rows.

[image]

So the 1st column will be Counter and 2nd column will be difference of current row Counter and previous Counter. Here is an example:

[image]

I was thinking to write something like:

```
select 
  id,
  counter - LAG(counter, 1) OVER (ORDER BY counter)
from table
```

Here is what is the result of my query:
[image]
I am using Google Bigquery.

Comment: Why is the `id` the same in all rows?  What is the issue with your query?

Comment: There are several IDs . That is a sample output. I will add a sample output now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your counter is never decreasing *and* you want the results per `id`, then you are on the right track.  I think you want:

```
select id, counter,
       counter - lag(counter) over (partition by id order by counter) as diff
from table
order by id, counter;
```

Note:  This includes the `id` as the first column because it seems relevant.

Comment: Thank you so much, It seems the 1 that I added to Lag changed the answer. your solution works. Thank you again. I will accept the answer asap